# Create a Samba share in Ubuntu Server

Tags: linux, ubuntu, samba, network-share

I just have Ubuntu server installed and i want a SMB server. So i got Samba all set up but now i wonder how to create a 'share', in Windows you would just go to Properties/Sharing/Advanced sharing, but i don't really know how to make one in Linux with Samba. I made a user with `smbpasswd -a mylinuxusername`, but that isnt the share name. Using `net view \\myservername` shows no shares at all, but i'm sure Samba is running.

Please explain the 'shares' in Samba.

Comment: Edit the file `/etc/samba/smb.conf`.  See http://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/manpages-3/smb.conf.5.html and http://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/Samba-HOWTO-Collection/

Comment: @Zoredache Ok, but if you say something like this please post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

You have to go to the configuration file with e.g. this command

```
nano /etc/samba/smb.conf
```

and then scroll down using the arrows of your keyboard.

You can create a simple share using the following lines:

```
[exampleShare]
     path = /srv/shares/exampleShare
     available = yes
     browseable = yes
     writeable = yes
     guest ok = no
```

Comment: Thanks! That solved it.You can accept this answer in 6 minutes :(